# Problemas con las ventana modal de bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, modal

Hola buenas noches espero que puedan ayudarme.

Estoy haciendo una tienda virtual, guardo los datos que necesito en un arreglo bidimensional y los voy agregando a medida que los necesito en la cuadricula de productos, esto lo hago con un while, mientras que halla articulos que mostrar, array_art es el arreglo, cada fila el, i, es un articulo y cada columna es un dato distinto de ese articulo. 
La idea es que al hacer click en la descripcion o el numero de articulo abra una ventana modal con mas detalles del mismo. Utilizo bootstrap.

Lo que sucede es que la modal queda detras, probe con z-index, no funciono. Agrege fotos de como se ve y ademas de la consola, parece que esta tomando bien el id de la ventana modal y el href del boton. Probe a poner los links de bootstrap al final del body, al principio en el head, todas la opciones que se me ocurrieron y no funciona queda asi.

Cuando clikeo el enlace se queda exactamente igual, en la barra de navegacion aparece la ruta como deberia ninios.php# y el numero del id.

Adjunto los codigos del boton y de la modal, esta todo en la misma pagina pero los agregue por separado porque eran muy largos sino.

Estoy utilizando chorme, pero en otros navegadores sucede lo mismo.
La version de bootstrap es la 4.2.1.

Desde agradezco cualquier ayuda

[image: Captura de pantalla]

**texto en negrita**[image: Captura de pantalla]

Codigo de la cuadricula

```html
<?php 
$i=0;
while ($i<$c) {
  echo '<div class="product-item">';
    echo '<img class="img_art" src="' . $array_art[$i][2] . '">';
    if ($array_art[$i][3]<>0){
        echo '<div class="img_detalles">';
        echo '<img src="' . $array_art[$i][4] . '">';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '<div class="more">';
        echo '<p> Ver colores y talles </p>';
   echo '</div>';
   echo '<div class="art">';
   //ESTE ES EL HREF QUE DEBERIA ABRIR LA MODAL
       echo '<a class="articulo" href="#' . $array_art[$i][0] . '" data-toggle="modal" >';
         echo "<span>" . $array_art[$i][0] .  "</br></span>";
         echo "<span>" . $array_art[$i][1] .  "</br></span>";
  echo '</a>';
   echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
 $i++;
}
?>
```

Codigo de la ventana modal

```html
<?php
  $i=0;
  while ($i<$c) {
   echo '<div class="modal fade" id="' . $array_art[$i][0] . '">';
echo '<div class="modal-dialog">';
 echo '<div class="modal-content">';
  echo '<div class="modal-header">';
   echo '<h6 class="modal-title">' . $array_art[$i][1] . '</h6>';
    echo '<button tytle="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';
     echo '</div>'; //modal header
   echo '<div class="modal-body">';
     //TODO EL CODIGO 
   echo '</div>';//modal body  
 echo '</div>';//modal content
echo '</div>';//detalles
   echo '</div>';//modal dailogo
 echo '</div>';//modal
```

Comment: Tienes una versión en vivo en la cuál podamos probar?, acá puedes editar la pregunta utilizando el editor de código como hiciste pero colocando el html directo sin usar php y enlazando el bootstrap, tu css, etc... Se hace muy dificil ayudarte si no podemos reproducir el comportamiento. Por otra parte, yo intentaría colocarle un z-index: 10000 !important solo para probar (se que indicaste que lo probaste pero no se si lo hiciste con el flag !important). saludos

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero ya encontre el error y estaba trayendo dos versiones de query que ocasionaban eso.